# Remote SVN administration

Tags: java, svn

I'm writing a Java app that performs various SVN actions (commit, copy, etc) from a remote machine. I access SVN from my Java app using the SVNKit API.

I also need to perform some administration actions, such as creating users and repositories. These actions are not available via the SVNKit API, or even the SVN command-line interface. Normally these would be performed directly on the SVN server, using [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09s02.html) or a GUI equivalent.

(It is possible with SVNKit to [create a local repository](https://wiki.svnkit.com/Setting_Up_A_Subversion_Repository#CreatingaSubversionrepositorywithSVNKit), but I need to create a repository on a remote machine)

So it seems my options are:

1. Programatically connect from java
   app to svn server using SSH or
   similar, then use `Runtime.exec()`
   to run `svnadmin`
2. Deploy a web application (like [this one](http://svnmanager.org/)) on machine running svn server, then connect to it from java app using HTTP
3. Map a drive from java app machine to svn server machine (both are windows machines), then run `svnadmin` from the former, supplying the path to the latter as an argument

Is there any other way to perform these admin tasks from a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Since `svnadmin` does not itself work remotely (as stated explicitly in its documentation), your problem is no different from running any other local application from a remote computer.

BTW, your option 3 [is not advisable](http://registration.fay-ar.us/pub/subversion/Book/ch05s02.html):

> Do not create a Berkeley DB repository
>   on a network share—it cannot exist on
>   a remote filesystem such as NFS, AFS,
>   or Windows SMB. Berkeley DB requires
>   that the underlying filesystem
>   implement strict POSIX locking
>   semantics, and more importantly, the
>   ability to map files directly into
>   process memory. Almost no network
>   filesystems provide these features. If
>   you attempt to use Berkeley DB on a
>   network share, the results are
>   unpredictable—you may see mysterious
>   errors right away, or it may be months
>   before you discover that your
>   repository database is subtly
>   corrupted.

Comment: I'll be creating an FSFS repository, so this warning is irrelevant (but thanks for the info)